# Serial Port Spy for Windows Embedded CE

Tags: serial-port, windows-ce

Is there a serial port "Spy" application available for Windows CE? By spy I mean an application that runs on Windows CE and can monitor the traffic going in and out of a serial device without modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.virtualserialport.com/products/vspdce/) is a product that will do your job, but you need to pay for it. It basically works by creating virtual ports. You can do that yourself if you want to. Start from this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/DemoDriver.aspx) at Code Project. This will show you how you can create a serial port driver. You need to add code that will log ingoing/outcoming traffic while at the same time transferring data to/from a real port.

Comment: I already have a virtual serial driver, but it doesn't work for my needs because I would have to close the previously existing COM port. I was hoping to find something that works via call interception like an application verifier shim. I think I'll have to write my own.